# Loop through all characters in XML file and replace certain characters

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, excel

After finally getting my XmlReader to work correctly on a project at work, I am now getting certain parsing errors when trying to create new Reader objects for certain XML files. For instance, this one that keeps occurring is an error trying to parse a hyphen (-). This slightly baffles me because I manually go in and replace that character with something else (like an underscore), and it reads fine - even when there are hyphens elsewhere in the document that are not changed.

So, unless there is a explanation to fix this (maybe some XmlReaderSettings? Have yet to use any so I don't know what they are capable of), what is the best syntax/method to cycle through every character and replace with ones that will parse correctly?

This program will run automatically once per day on a daily-added XML and length of run-time is not an issue.

Edit: Error Message:

System.Xml.XmlException: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 2896, position 89.

Code:

```
            FN = Path.GetFileName(file1).ToString()
        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(Path.Combine(My.Settings.Local_Meter_Path, FN), New XmlReaderSettings())
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(13)
        Dim filecreatedate As String = IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file1)
```

Comment: <Cell ss:StyleID="Default"><Data ss:Type="String">1440 COUNTY ROAD 40  X-MAS LIGHT & RV #2 CAMP HILL</Data></Cell>

Comment: Error occurs at the "-" in X-Mas

Comment: Very strange. Can you show parse exception message? Put message in the question by editing it.

Comment: Alright, I edited it. The position 89 is right at that hyphen after the X. And what I don't get is why the numerous other hyphens elsewhere in the document dont get the same treatment

Answer (score 0):

If the problem occurs in ONLY ONE HYPHEN in entire file, even if the file contains more hyphens, the problem may be related to:

1) The HYPHEN is really not an HYPHEN but a control-character or even be accomplished of a hidden control character.

2) The link has other interesting thinhs, like an ampersand ("&"), which in strings may cause some problems. Are you sure the problem is the Hyphen?

Comment: Yea the line and character location correspond to the hyphen, as listed above. After removing that, the XMLReader works fine - even though there are other hyphens

Comment: If the problem is related to that SPECIFIC hyphen, as I said, the problem may be related to a control-char instead an hyphen. Try to see the ASCII code of this hyphen to see if it´s under ASC(45).  Do you have ANY variable X in the same routine? Something that could be interpreted as "40-x"?